# Loading UserData never occurs in Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

So I been tryng to call User data for a while now and I actually have a few hurdles. First I tried to use a Stream, but then decided to move into a Future since Stream was not working where now I get this error.

```
Notifying id token listeners about user ( jIjnj3FjR0fg7EWI5RxK3J2SYGH3 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(16764): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( jIjnj3FjR0fg7EWI5RxK3J2SYGH3 ).
E/flutter (16764): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _LogInState#a1c31(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter (16764): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (16764): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (16764): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter (16764): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1204:9)
E/flutter (16764): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1239:6)
E/flutter (16764): #2      _LogInState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:SAT/screens/authentication/logIn.dart:116:33)
E/flutter (16764): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16764): #3      _LogInState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:SAT/screens/authentication/logIn.dart)
E/flutter (16764): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
E/flutter (16764): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
E/flutter (16764): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
E/flutter (16764): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
E/flutter (16764): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
E/flutter (16764): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:219:7)
E/flutter (16764): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:477:9)
E/flutter (16764): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:78:12)
E/flutter (16764): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:124:9)
E/flutter (16764): #13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (16764): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:18)
E/flutter (16764): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:108:7)
E/flutter (16764): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:220:19)
E/flutter (16764): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
E/flutter (16764): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
E/flutter (16764): #19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
E/flutter (16764): #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (16764): #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (16764): #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (16764): #23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (16764): #24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
E/flutter (16764): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
E/flutter (16764): 
W/DynamiteModule(16764): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(16764): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(16764): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/zygote  (16764): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/zygote  (16764): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto(16764): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(16764): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller(16764): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/zygote  (16764): Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=80KB
I/zygote  (16764): After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=80KB
I/zygote  (16764): Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

It all starts from main.dart which looks like this and generates a stream for user.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:MyApp/screens/authentication/handler.dart';

import 'package:MyApp/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/services/geolocator.dart';

import 'package:MyApp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final locatorService = GeolocatorService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>.value(
          value: AuthService().user,
        ),
        FutureProvider(create: (context) => locatorService.getLocation)
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
          accentColor: Colors.black,
          canvasColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        initialRoute: "/",
        routes: {
          "/": (ctx) => Handler(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then passes through the handler which does this:

```
import 'package:MyApp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/screens/clientSide/home.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/screens/authentication/authenticate.dart';

class Handler extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    // return either the Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

Now after doing that it listens for a user not being null which is only changed by my auth.dart service when register or signIn functions are called.

```
import 'package:MyApp/services/database.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on firebase user
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  // sign in with email and password
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // register with email and password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password,
      Timestamp birthdate, String firstName, String lastName) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      // Create User in Collection
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid)
          .createUserData(firstName, lastName, email, birthdate);
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

My code which crashes and needs to be fixed starts in home.dart which looks like this:

```
import 'package:MyApp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/services/database.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/services/language.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/services/time.dart';

import 'package:MyApp/widgets/shared/loading.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  String _mapStyle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentPosition = Provider.of<Position>(context);
    var activeLanguage = Provider.of<Language>(context).getLanguage;
    var mapChange = Provider.of<TimeService>(context).getTheme;

    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return FutureBuilder<UserData>(
      future: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
          while (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Loading();
         }
    UserData userData = snapshot.data;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        title: Text('MyApp',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 27,
            )),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
              child:Text('Log Out',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black)),
              onPressed: () {
               print("Log Out"),
              }),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF222222),
                    child: Text(
                       '${userData.firstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${userData.lastName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 48),
                    ),
                    radius: 50.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
                  ),
                  Text(
                     "${userData.firstName} ${userData.lastName}",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ],
        ),
      ),
      body: (currentPosition != null)
          ? Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                GoogleMap(
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    mapController = controller;
                    if (mapChange == false) {
                      rootBundle
                          .loadString('lib/assets/maps/DarkStyle.txt')
                          .then((string) {
                        _mapStyle = string;
                      });
                    } else {
                      rootBundle
                          .loadString('lib/assets/maps/LightStyle.txt')
                          .then((string) {
                        _mapStyle = string;
                      });
                    }
                    mapController.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
                  },
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(
                        currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude),
                    zoom: 12.0,
                  ),
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                ),
              ],
            )
          : Center(child: Loading()),
    );
   });
  }
}
```

As you might see it's extremely dependent of the Database Service which is this code.

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('Users');

  Future<void> createUserData(String firstName, String lastName, String email,
      Timestamp birthDay) async {
    return await userCollection.document(uid).setData({
      "id": uid,
      "email": email,
      "firstName": firstName,
      "lastName": lastName,
      "birthdDay": birthDay,
      "driver": false,
      "business": false,
      "admin": false,
      "towTruck": false,
      "orders": orders,
      "homeLocation": null,
      "activeLanguage": false,
      "activeTheme": false,
      "dateCreated": Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()),
    });
  }

  // user data from snapshots
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
        uid: snapshot.data['id'],
        email: snapshot.data['email'],
        firstName: snapshot.data['firstName'],
        lastName: snapshot.data['lastName'],
        birthDay: snapshot.data['birthday'],
        driver: snapshot.data['driver'],
        business: snapshot.data['business'],
        admin: snapshot.data['admin'],
        orders: snapshot.data['orders'],
        towTruck: snapshot.data['towTruck'],
        homeLocation: snapshot.data['towTruck'],
        activeLanguage: snapshot.data['activeLanguage'],
        activeTheme: snapshot.data['activeTheme']);
  }

  // get user doc stream
  Future<UserData> get userData async {
    DocumentReference userReference = userCollection.document(uid);
    DocumentSnapshot userRef = await userReference.get();
    return _userDataFromSnapshot(userRef);
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could explain how to fix this and if there is a chance to change it into a stream then I would also appreciate an answer.

I'm pretty new to dart and flutter would really appreciate code explanation for solution.

Comment: There's more to the code.  It's saying the widget is being rebuilt after a widget it depends on is already disposed.  Are there any navigations to another page?

Comment: @ScottGodfrey The other thing that comes to mind is that the user is a stream itself and after the user gets authenticated it switches from the log in screen to this screen through a handler. Should I add that code to the question just in case?

Comment: Yes, this might be where the problem occurs.

Comment: @ScottGodfrey I edited the problem entirely.

Comment: It's actually pointing to your login.dart file.